# Reduce mac os framework size

Tags: macos, sqlite, icu

I'm developing mac os framework with custom sqlite build with ICU. It's size is about 25Mb. Is there any way to reduce framework size? I tried all required flags (strip dead code etc.), but it just 500Kb smaller. Framework includes ICU and Sqlite libraries. If I use these libraries for command line application it's quite small.

Comment: A good portion of the bulk is likely the ICU data that is likely included in the framework. You could for example use the ICU data customizer to reduce the size by removing what you don't need or have it reference an external .dat file (but then, you'd just be moving the bulk elsewhere)

Comment: Yes, ICU is the largest part of it.

Comment: You missed the keyword: data. It's ICU's *data* that is the large portion. Please re-read my comment.

Comment: Yes, ICU data part is about 25Mb. I'll investigate about customization. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to expand on @NuSkooler 's point - http://userguide.icu-project.org/icudata discusses reducing data size (including customizer) and http://userguide.icu-project.org/packaging#TOC-Making-ICU-Smaller discusses making the code smaller.